# How would I split a stream in Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I am not understanding how I would split a stream in Apache Storm.  For example, I have bolt A that after some computation has somevalue1, somevalue2, and somevalue3.  It wants to send somevalue1 to bolt B, somevalue2 to bolt C, and somevalue1,somevalue2 to bolt D.  How would I do this in Storm?  What grouping would I use and what would my topology look like? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use different streams if your case needs that, it is not really splitting, but you will have a lot of flexibility, you could use it for content based routing from a bolt for instance:

You declare the stream in the bolt:

```
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(final OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
    outputFieldsDeclarer.declareStream("stream1", new Fields("field1"));
    outputFieldsDeclarer.declareStream("stream2", new Fields("field1"));
}
```

You emit from the bolt on the chosen stream:

```
collector.emit("stream1", new Values("field1Value"));
```

You listen to the correct stream through the topology

```
builder.setBolt("myBolt1", new MyBolt1()).shuffleGrouping("boltWithStreams", "stream1");
builder.setBolt("myBolt2", new MyBolt2()).shuffleGrouping("boltWithStreams", "stream2");
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for this in Trident ?

Comment: @zenbeni When you emit this new stream from the bolt, you are not anchoring it. In such a case, is a separate tree formed? If there is a failure in "stream1", would the spout or bolt ever know that anything went wrong?

Comment: One can emit to stream while anchoring - there is an additional overload of emit method for that.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here: [Stream Groups](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial#stream-groupings) and *"Direct Grouping"*. Depending on your requirements, one of them is going to serves you.

Have a look at WordCountTopology sample project to see whether that is what you are looking for. Otherwise, *"Direct Grouping"* is going to be a better alternative.

But again, picking a grouping strategy depends on your requirements.