# Tick Tuples in two different Bolts with different frequency

Tags: java, apache-storm

I want to do two different periodic task in tow different bolts at different frequency. First task works at 1 hour frequency while the second one works at `30s` frequency. I want to know the behavior of Storm tuples in such cases. Will the tick tuple of one bolt be visible in other one.
That is to say will the Bolt one receive tuple of bolt 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can create spout that emit to 2 different stream by using name stream.
Your spout will run every 30S and emit for the first bolt and every 1H it will emit to bolt 2

Check [this good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807395/how-would-i-split-a-stream-in-apache-storm) example

Comment: I don't want to create any separate spout for that purpose. In fact, the purpose of Tick tuples in storm was to eliminate this kind of problem.