# How to dispatch tuple to different blot in storm

Tags: stream, grouping, apache-storm

everyone.I want to do the job—— one spout emit numbers to blotA,and BlotA emit odd number to Blot_odd ,  BlotA emit even number to Blot_even.
I choose one way to use `emit(streamId,tuple)`,but I don't know where to define my streamId?

In the Blot_odd / Blot_even ,

```java
declareOutputFields(){declarer.declareStream("streamId", new Fields("fieldName"));}
```

and in `main` of `MyTopology.java`

```java
main() {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("num", new NumSpout(), 10);
    builder.setBolt("judge", new Bolt(), 3).shuffleGrouping("num");
    builder.setBolt("odd", new Bolt_odd(), 2).shuffleGrouping("judge");
    builder.setBolt("even", new Bolt_even(), 2).shuffleGrouping("judge");
}
```

but I failed.

Comment: please provide your code for new Bolt(), new Bolt_odd() and new Bolt_even() .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I split a stream in Apache Storm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807395/how-would-i-split-a-stream-in-apache-storm)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below.

in declareOutputFields method of Bolt, fill in the details like this.

```
declarer.declareStream("oddstream", new Fields("fieldName"));
declarer.declareStream("evenstream", new Fields("fieldName"));
```

And you can declare topology like below.

```
builder.setSpout("num", new NumSpout(), 10);
builder.setBolt("judge", new Bolt(), 3).shuffleGrouping("num");
builder.setBolt("odd", new Bolt_odd(), 2).shuffleGrouping("judge", "oddstream");
builder.setBolt("even", new Bolt_even(), 2).shuffleGrouping("judge", "evenstream");
```