# fieldsGrouping on a a particular stream in Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I can see we've shuffleGrouping available for a particular stream in Storm as described here: [How would I split a stream in Apache Storm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807395/how-would-i-split-a-stream-in-apache-storm)

```
builder.setBolt("myBolt1", new MyBolt1()).shuffleGrouping("SpoutWithStreams", "stream1");
```

But I've a use case where I would want to have fieldsGrouping on a particular stream emitted by a spout.

For Eg. **SpoutWithStreams** is emitting **stream1** with random words, I want **myBolt1** to subscribe to this stream, but I also want a particular instance of **myBolt1** to receive same words i.e I want fieldsGrouping on **stream1**.

So what I want is something like this:

```
builder.setBolt("myBolt1", new MyBolt1()).fieldsGrouping("boltWithStreams", "stream1","field");
```

I don't want to have an extra bolt just for fieldsGrouping. Any other alternatives?

Comment: I don't understand want you mead by "I don't want to have an extra bolt just for fieldsGrouping.".. Can you explain in more detail what you wan to accomplish?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I've added an example to the question. Hope it makes more sense now. I just meant that I can have a separate bolt to subscribe to stream1 and then myBolt1 can subscribe to that bolt using fieldsGrouping.

Comment: I still not sure if I get it. However, I get the impression that you have some miss understanding how Storm works. If your Spout emits random words and you want to receive those words via fieldGrouping, you can just subscribe to this "random stream" via fieldsGrouping. There is no need to emit a grouped stream to be able to use fieldsGrouping (Storm will take care of everything internally, and repartition your data).

Comment: I could have done that, but I emit only particular kind of words to this stream. All other sentences and words are emitted to another stream for different kind of bolts. I've been working on storm from quite a while now so I understand it pretty well.

Comment: Ok. Seems my impression was wrong. Nevertheless, I still do not understand what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Due to not well-defined question, I will take a guess as to what you mean and try to answer.

I am guessing you want to receive two streams in your bolt, where one stream is a shuffleGrouping from another bolt and the other stream is a fieldsGrouping from a spout.

If this is the case, you can do something like that:

```
builder.setBolt("myBolt1", new MyBolt1()).shuffleGrouping("boltWithStreams", "stream1").fieldsGrouping("spout", "stream2", new Fields("field"));
```

and then in your bolt you can distinguish if the tuple belongs to one stream or the other using:

```
if (tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals("stream1"){
    //do something
} else if (tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals("stream2"){
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not what I wanted. I've added an example to the question. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: I am still not exactly sure what you need to accomplish. If I understand correctly, you want to perform a "self-loop", and emit a fieldsGrouping from the bolt to itself (to a specific task of the same bolt). This can be done using the `BoltDeclarer` like so: 
`BoltDeclarer bolt1 = builder.setBolt("myBolt1", new MyBolt1()).shuffleGrouping("SpoutWithStreams", "stream1");
bolt1.fieldsGrouping("myBolt1", "stream1",new Fields("field"));`